# Rounding numbers in a list to csv

Tags: python, csv

I have a list which is storing an address like this:

```
data = [customer name,address,parcel number, parcel weight, etc]
```

When making my new .csv file instead of getting the value 1 I am getting 1.0, how can I correct the numbers within my list to not have the decimal point?

My current code:

```
 def retrieve_input():
    inputValue = textBox1.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    inputValue2 = textBox2.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    inputValue3 = textBox3.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    sheet.range('B10').value = (inputValue)
    sheet.range('C10').value = (inputValue2)
    sheet.range('D10').value = (inputValue3)

    print(inputValue)

    # Read values to a list named data
    data = sheet.range('I9:T10').value
    print(data)

    with open("C:\DPD\out.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(data)
```

Comment: Can you share the code you're using to create the .csv file?

Comment: I added the code that was posted as an answer in an edit, it will be seen as soon as the edit is approved.